# Grabbing docusign envelope status and recipients in a single API call

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the docusign api and am having some trouble with a query string param. Basically I'm trying to grab the recipient information of an envelope along with the status of the envelope in a single call.

I am able to grab each of information individually with the following api calls and they both work

1.) Envelope endpoint (has a status field with overall envelope status such as Signed, Voided, Declined, etc...):
**https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/:accountId/envelopes/:docusignEnvelopeId/**

2.) Envelope/recipients endpoint (has information regarding recipients)
**https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/:accountId/envelopes/:docusignEnvelopeId/recipients**

However, I'm trying to see if I can grab these information all within one API call. According to the docs here for the general envelope endpoint, I think I should be able to with a query param
**https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/get#request**.

Under the include Optional Query Parameters section, there's a param for "include" which says I can grab recipients from the 1st endpoint. "Specifies additional information about the envelope to return. Enter a comma-separated list, such as tabs,recipients. Valid values are..."

I've been trying to modify the first endpoint with this include param to look something like this...

**https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/:accountId/envelopes/:docusignEnvelopeId?include=recipients**

But I have been unable to have recipients show up as well. Was wondering if I'm just typing in the param wrong or if this is not available anymore. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `include` parameters were added in v2.1 of the eSignature API, so they don't work in v2. Changing your URL to `https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/:accountId/envelopes/:docusignEnvelopeId?include=recipients` should return the recipient info.